# Delete all rows except last row in a table JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could it be possible?

I tried:

```js
$("#tbl1 tbody").empty().append(markup)
var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl1")
var lastRow = tbl.rows[tbl.rows.length - 1];
$("#tbl2 tbody").append(lastRow)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy all you have to do is check if it's not the last row then remove. Refer below-mentioned code to remove every row except last.

```
$("table tr:not(:last)").remove()
```